# RN: Don't ask for push notification permissions on initial open

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios

I am using https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/ to handle push notifications in my React Native app. It works, but I don't want the user to see the notification permission prompt until I explicitly call it later on. This is what happens on load:

[image]

I have uncommented every line of code from this library, but it still asks for this on app load. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want the user to see your push notifications as foreground notifications (i.e. visible popup on screen on receiving a notification), you will always need to ask permission. The entire reason for permissions is so that app developers can't go wild and spam the user, or worse, gain access to things such as Photos or Messages without user's consent. You can however use [Provisional notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications), which will show the notification in notification center without permission popup.

Comment: No, that's not my problem. I'm not asking not to show this dialogue, I'm asking not to show it until we want to (i.e. on registration). For now, it shows up when the app is opened, and I don't invoke it.

Comment: BTW the reason the popup is triggered on app load is because the device has to be registered with what ever cloud messaging service you are using to be able to receive tokens. It would help if you tell us which cloud messaging provider you are using (i.e. `react-native-firebase`).

Comment: I honestly don't know what provider I'm using. Pushkit? Can I find out?

Comment: I'm using react-native-firebase, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove this in `AppDelagate.m`:

```
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *_Nullable error) {
}];
```

Comment: Hey, I do not have it in my AppDelagate.m file, what do I do? Can you check my [app delegate](https://gist.github.com/Nodirbek-Sharipov/173c15ba71924ccf892f6a238597fb83) file please?